# How to load pictures from a list asyncron, to show the text first

Tags: delphi

I want to load a list with thumbnail pictures from the internet. In order to have a good user experiance, I want to load and display the text of the list first, and want to load the pictures from the list in a background thread. When a picture is downloaded I want to show it in (refresh) the correspondig row of the list. 
Actually, I don't know where to start. Can I use a `TClientDataset` component to load the text first and load the pictures in a background thread and insert it with `.Locate()` `.Edit` `.Post` to the dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `TClientDataSet` for requesting the data directly, **except** the picture. Thus, the fetching of the main data should be fast enough.

You should load the picture as a *calculated field* then. [Documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/fhxr25728_xml.html) says (with my own emphasis):

> A calculated field displays values calculated at runtime by a
>   dataset's `OnCalcFields` event handler. For example, you might create a
>   string field that displays concatenated values from other fields.
>
> To create a calculated field in the *New Field* dialog box
>
> 1. Enter a name for the calculated field in the *Name* edit box. Do not enter the name of an existing field.
> 2. Choose a data type for the field from the *Type* combo box.
> 3. Enter the size of the field in the *Size* edit box, if appropriate. Size is only relevant for fields of type `TStringField`, `TBytesField`, and `TVarBytesField`.
> 4. Select *Calculated* or *InternalCalc* in the *Field type* radio group. *InternalCalc* is only available if you are working with a client dataset. The significant difference between these types of calculated fields is that the values calculated for an InternalCalc field are stored and retrieved as part of the client dataset's data.
> 5. Choose OK. The newly defined calculated field is automatically added to the end of the list of persistent fields in the Field editor list box, and the component declaration is automatically added to the form's or data module's type declaration.
> 6. Place code that calculates values for the field in the `OnCalcFields` event handler for the dataset. For more information about writing code to calculate field values, see [Programming a calculated field](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/fhxr14702_xml.html).

In `OnCalcFields` event handler you then need to implement asynchron loading of the picture.

Comment: "except the picture" The picture is data also. What about `TDataSetProvider  FetchBlobOnDemand` flag?

Comment: @ValMarinov Of course, the picture is also data. But it should not be loaded with the other data. I don't think, that `FetchBlobOnDemand` provides a capability for loading the pictures asynchronly.

Comment: `FetchBlobOnDemand` provides the ability to load data from blob fields  when you need them.

Comment: @ValMarinov Usually, "when you need them" is when the records are shown. `TClientDataSet.FetchOnDemand` (which is `True`by default) does the same for the dataset itself. Problem is, the more records are made visible, the more pictures will be fetched, too. That can block the main thread for some significant time. Essentially, "to load data when you need them" is not the same as "to load data asynchronously when you need them".

Comment: @RenéHoffmann: Just tested OnCalcFields. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, since it only gets triggered when you move the cursor.

Comment: @markus_ja That's the expected behaviour. How do you load more than one item without moving the cursor (aka scrolling)?